# Jasmine: callThrough with Promise return fails (Jasmine 2.x & Angular.io)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, jasmine

I've problem with my angular.io tests with jasmine (v2.99). 
I've created a spyObject for an angular service and mocked some functions. It worked as expected. Now i want to call an original function (not-mock) in the same service. This function returns a promise.
I've seen that is done with callThrough() in jasmine.
So, that is what i've done. And it works up to a certain extent ;)

```
     describe('Component2Test',()=>{

      let component: Component2Test;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component2Test>;
      let dataServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<DataService>;

                    beforeEach(() => {

                        const dataSrvSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('DataService', ['getUserObject', 
                       'getLocalStorageObject','getAllLocalStorageKeys','setLocalStorageObject']);
                        dataSrvSpy.getUserObject.and.returnValue(tua);
                        dataSrvSpy.getAllLocalStorageKeys.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(localStorageData));
                        dataSrvSpy.setLocalStorageObject.and.callThrough(); <--- ?????
                 }

     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [],
          declarations: [Component2Test],
          providers: [
            {provide: DataService, useValue: dataSrvSpy},
          ]
        });

        dataServiceSpy = TestBed.get(DataService);

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component2Test);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

});
```

test

```
 fit('should set data in localStorage', fakeAsync(() => {


dataServiceSpy.setLocalStorageObject(foundData[foundDataKeys[1]],foundDataKeys[1]).then();

    });
```

Although the original function is called and i can see the data is written as i expected. Unfortunately jasmine returned with this error message

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

original function in service

```
 setLocalStorageObject(o:object,key:string):Promise<boolean>{
          return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

           this._lclStrgSrv4User.storeJsonDataInLocalStorage(o,key).then((resp)=>{
              resolve(resp);
            },(err)=>{
              reject(err)
            });
          })
        }
```

So, my question is:
How can i define the callThrough() correctly ?

Thanks in advance, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using createSpyObj, you are creating "bare" spys. There is no implementation behind those. It is normal that it's returning undefined.

You should create you own mock of the DataService or provide the real service, then add spyOns to intercept calls.
The callThrough() should work then.

Comment: Thanks Zak, you point me in the right direction. I had misunderstood the concept of createSpy.